# ts-node only works when indirectly ran by npm run script

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, ts-node

If I try `ts-node src/main.ts`, I get

```
$ ts-node src/main.ts                                                                                                                  ↵ 1  04:15:21
/home/mm/proj/university-bot/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42537
        ts.Debug.assert(typeof typeReferenceDirectiveName === "string", "Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.");
                 ^
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirective (/home/mm/proj/university-bot/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42537:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/resolver-functions.ts:131:51
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirectives (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/resolver-functions.ts:130:31)
    at actualResolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (/home/mm/proj/university-bot/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116674:163)
    at resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (/home/mm/proj/university-bot/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116974:26)
    at processTypeReferenceDirectives (/home/mm/proj/university-bot/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118456:31)
    at findSourceFileWorker (/home/mm/proj/university-bot/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118341:21)
    at findSourceFile (/home/mm/proj/university-bot/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118196:26)
    at processImportedModules (/home/mm/proj/university-bot/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118602:25)
```

but when I run `npm run start`, which resolves to `ts-node src/main.ts`, it works

```
$ npm run start                                                                                                                        ↵ 1  04:17:59

> university-bot@1.0.0 start
> ts-node src/main.ts

Ready!
```

my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "university-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/main.ts",
    "deploy": "ts-node src/deploy-commands.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Michael Moreno",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^0.15.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.5.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.35.0",
    "discord.js": "^13.8.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: `ts-node` and `npm run start` could call two different versions of `ts-node`. `npm run` adds `node_modules/.bin` to the `PATH`.

Comment: it looks like ts-node is installed globally and npm script is running the one defined by package.json. So theyre probbly different versions.